# How to draw trapezoid shape in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I need help to draw trapezoid shapes in iOS.

I am using the following code to draw the Pink shape, but it is not working:

```
UIBezierPath* trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[trianglePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(topView.frame.size.width, topView.frame.size.height/2)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, topView.frame.size.height/2)];

CAShapeLayer *triangleMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[triangleMaskLayer setPath:trianglePath.CGPath];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,topView.frame.size.height-150, 200, 150)];
view.layer.mask = triangleMaskLayer;
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

How can I draw the pink-colored shape?[image]

Comment: You didn't use `triangleMaskLayer`.

Comment: Sorry typo problem updated @Larme

Comment: sry, but what pink shape are u talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)TriangularPinkView{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.5;

    CGPoint start = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.pinkView.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.pinkView.frame)+CGRectGetHeight(self.pinkView.frame)*.25);
    [path moveToPoint:start];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.pinkView.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.pinkView.frame))];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.pinkView.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.pinkView.frame))];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.pinkView.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.pinkView.frame))];


    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
//    shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```